# apache shiro: what to add in shiro.ini for client authentication using JWT with keycloak as authorization server

Tags: jwt, shiro, keycloak

I am very new to shiro and keycloak, I don't know how to add JWT configuration into shiro.ini for authenticating user using keycloak as authorization server.

Comment: I haven't used Shiro myself, but having read the docs it looks like it overlaps with KC. Do you have any reason to use both?

Comment: yes, actually i have built rest api in java and i want to protect that rest api using shiro. so if a user opens browser and visit that rest url, shiro will redirect it to keycloak for authentication and after authentication that user can access url.

Comment: You might use this extension to integrate Shiro with OpenId Connect: https://github.com/bujiio/buji-pac4j

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to archive with your resource and authorisation server looks like the rfc6749 [Implicit Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2). Shiro brings no filter implementation for anything like this out of the box. You might have to write your own custom [`Filter`](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.4.0/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/web/filter/authc/AuthenticatingFilter.html), [`Realm`](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.4.0/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/realm/AuthorizingRealm.html), [`Token`](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.4.0/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/authc/AuthenticationToken.html), [`Info`](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.4.0/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/authc/AuthenticationInfo.html), [`Matcher`](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.4.0/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/authc/credential/CredentialsMatcher.html) and [`Principal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html) for this.

Alternatively there is a oAuth2 [Server](https://github.com/zhangkaitao/shiro-example/tree/master/shiro-example-chapter17-server) and [Client](https://github.com/zhangkaitao/shiro-example/tree/master/shiro-example-chapter17-client) example on GitHub using Shiro and implementing the mentioned classes. Its outdated but still gives the basic idea what you need to do.

If you don't like to follow the [rfc6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) specification you can simply implement an [`AccessControlFilter`](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.4.0/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/web/filter/AccessControlFilter.html) and redirect your user to the authorisation server if no bearer is present in the `Authorization` header of the request. There is already an tutorial on how to achieve this [here](https://blog.novatec-gmbh.de/json-web-token-apache-shiro/). In particular you should look at the `onAccessDenied` code from the examples `JWTVerifyingFilter` since this is the method where your redirect should take place.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you follow the [buji-pac4j-demo](https://github.com/pac4j/buji-pac4j-demo) and take a look at the [shiro.ini](https://github.com/pac4j/buji-pac4j-demo/blob/master/src/main/resources/shiro.ini) file there. it has a implementations for different web service authentication protocols (including JWT).

I believe this is the relevant snippet:

```
signingConfig = org.pac4j.jwt.config.signature.SecretSignatureConfiguration
signingConfig.secret = 12345678901234567890123456789012
encryptionConfig = org.pac4j.jwt.config.encryption.SecretEncryptionConfiguration
encryptionConfig.secret = 12345678901234567890123456789012

jwtAuthenticator = org.pac4j.jwt.credentials.authenticator.JwtAuthenticator
jwtAuthenticator.signatureConfiguration = $signingConfig
jwtAuthenticator.encryptionConfiguration = $encryptionConfig

parameterClient = org.pac4j.http.client.direct.ParameterClient
parameterClient.parameterName = token
parameterClient.authenticator = $jwtAuthenticator
parameterClient.supportGetRequest = true
parameterClient.supportPostRequest = false
```